# Splice function php

Tags: php

I can't understand how the splice function is working.
If I have these two arrays, I want to replace the array after an offset
Let's say I want to replace after the '2'

`$t=array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$t2=array(0,0);`

What should I do to get `[1,2,0,0]`
I tried this, but obviously not working `array_splice($t,2,0,$t2)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php), We can see that your offset is wrong.

Right now, your third parameter is 0, meaning that amount of items we need to replace is 0.

This will do the trick:

```
array_splice($t, 2, count($t), $t2);
```

You can try it out [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29c55a1c73c45e88a2e8a6d91ba2402327dc3cc4) where it gives the following result:

> array(4) {   [0]=>   int(1)   [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)=>   int(2)   [2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29c55a1c73c45e88a2e8a6d91ba2402327dc3cc4)=>   int(0)   [3]=> 
>   int(0) }

Bare in mind that when executing array_splice, two different results are available.

1. The return value of array_splice, which returns an array consisting of the extracted elements. (In this case, it would return 3, 4, 5, 6 because those are the elements that were removed)
2. Since we pass the array by reference, the array itself will contain the result you are looking for.

Comment: This is what I thought too but when I tried `$t=array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$t2=array(0,0);
var_dump(array_splice($t, 2, count($t), $t2));` I get `array(4) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) [2]=> int(5) [3]=> int(6) }`

Comment: That is because you are var_dumping the return value of array_splice. array_splice returns an array consisting of the extracted elements.

Since the first parameter of array_splice is an array passed by reference, you should use the $t array

Comment: Oh I got it, i printed the splice and not the result.